# Cannot modify header information - headers already sent during plugin activation

Tags: plugins, errors, headers, activation

I am getting this error

> PHP Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent
>   by (output started at
>   /home/zk2ba8xn663w/public_html/wp-includes/formatting.php:5100) in
>   /home/zk2ba8xn663w/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1219

The error message only shows up if i am activating from TGM plugin actiavtion page, ... if i first install through tgm and then go to actual plugin activation page redirect works with out any problem.

this is the redirect i am using

```
function activation_redirect( $plugin ) {
if( $plugin == plugin_basename( FILE ) ) {
exit( wp_redirect( admin_url( 'admin.php?page=general-settings' ) ) );
}
}
add_action( 'activated_plugin', 'activation_redirect' );
```

Comment: That would indicate you have something that is throwing an error during the activation processing.  It's difficult to track down without additional tools to gain more info on the actual error (which you'll need to know how to fix it). Consider using the "Debug Bar" and "Debug Bar Plugin Activation" plugins to get the actual PHP errors generated during plugin activation. Both are on wp.org

Comment: @butlerblog can the code i posted be the cause? if i remove that error goes but that does not make sense as there is no redirect there is no error :/.  Let me test with plugin you have mentioned

Comment: It probably is - although you wouldn't know for certain if you don't use something to get the actual PHP error (which is why I recommended the two tools mentioned - they are extremely helpful in plugin development).  I would say that your exit() needs to be separate and after the wp_redirect() call.  That's your likely problem.

Comment: And... I'd have to look for sure, but activated_plugin may be too late to actually run a wp_redirect() without a header error.

Comment: @butlerblog tested putting the exit() after redirect-  the error persists

Comment: I'd say you probably can't redirect where this is being fired then. wp_redirect() has to come *before* anything is sent downstream to the browser.

Comment: @butlerblog i tired all the plugins, but this is only line i get .  What are possible other alternatives for action? the action has to run during activation and before the headers ..i am confused

Comment: if the problem is onlt with TGM you should be looking at that, perhaps it also hooks `activated_plugin`? if so you could try adding a priority of 9 so as to run earlier... ie. `add_action( 'activated_plugin', 'activation_redirect',  9 );`

Comment: @majick wow thank you..that solves the problem! ..i always forgot about the priority part!..please add it as an answer!

Comment: sweet as! lucky guess but yeah it definitely gets you like that sometimes! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the standard redirection works, I figured the conflict must be with TGM plugin activation already hooking to `activated_plugin` and producing output and thus preventing the redirect...

Therefore the solution was to ensure that the plugin activation function hook was added to an earlier priority than the (silent) default of 10 most probably used by TGM:

```
add_action( 'activated_plugin', 'activation_redirect', 9 );
```